# Zend, redirect index.php to index.html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

My SEO wants me to rewrite index.php to index.html.

The probnlem is that I am using ZEND. When I go to index.php, I lands on my custom exception page, because Zend maybe don't want to understand that some SEO people that are external to PHP don't want to get index.php redirects to an exception page.

I understand Zend wants it all for PHP (And I am waiting them to rewrite an AngularJS version into PHP for Zend3) but.... meanwhile, I am stuck with Zend at the moment, and I can't figure out how I can modify my .htaccess.

At the moment, it looks like this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

If I add :

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.html [NC,L]
```

This breaks Zend.

Do I have to rename my index.php file to zend.php, and then, modify the last line to  :

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ zend.php [NC,L]
```

Or do I have to write a 1500 line long action helper code to make it the Zend way?

Comment: index.php shouldn't be appearing in your URLs anyway, so I'm not sure why this would be required. Can you give any example URLs you're trying to have redirected?

Comment: @TimFountain
index.php -> index.html
/ -> index.html

Comment: Okay well, ignoring how pointless this is for SEO (you need better SEO people), you need to solve this with routing, not in your htaccess. Are you using ZF1 or ZF2?

Comment: @TimFountain I understand your point with SEO 'science', it is extremely hard to differentiate a good SEO with a bad SEO. I am using ZF1.

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you are trying to do, tell me if I understand your background:
you have an application that uses AngularJS for the frontend and Zend Framework (and other related technologies) for the backend.

Giving priority to the index.html rather than index.php makes people visit mywebsite.com and see the AngularJS app.
Then they navigate the website and everything just works fine.

Here the issue: from the homepage they visit the url /path/to/content.html (or any other endpoint registered in your AngularJS app) and click the refresh button (or try to visit your website using directly the link /path/to/content.html) and what they see is a Zend exception. Why?

Because the /path/to/content.html doesn't exists as a file and there is no route registered in ZF that corresponds to that request.
How to fix this?

I can give you the solution I adopted, but I warn you that I use nginx and not apache, 
so you have to translate there rules.
Assuming that your AngularJS app uses the suffix .html for its pages

```
// priority to the index.html, the use index.php
index index.html index.php;

// other content here

// does the url ends with .html? force the request to end to index.html
// you can use any other discriminant
location ~ .*\.(html)?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Using this rule I am forcing the webserver to use the index.html when any request that ends with .html is received.
With this rule you can visit all your AngularJS endpoints directly and refreshing the page will work.

If you have webservices or other endpoints that needs the ZF app they'll continue to work.

But this is not enough to implement SEO in your website: even if direct link is now working, crawlers do not interpret js.
To solve this issue you need to serve crawler with the already interpreted version of your page. To make this work you will need a service called prerender.io (and a couple of other rules in the web server config).
Prerender.io internally uses PhantomJS that is like a command line browser that makes possible run js server side, so you will be able to serve an already composed webpage to crawler.

If you want to see a project of mine that uses AngularJS and have SEO please visit [neobazaar.com](https://www.neobazaar.com), it is far from being a perfect classifieds website but it has directlink and SEO, and uses AngularJS and ZF2 (sourcecode in github).

**EDIT #1**
This page can help with [Apache mode rewrite regexp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html).You can test the follow to see if it fits (I didn't test it):

```
RewriteRule ^*.html$ /index.html
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice answer. I voted it up. But it doesn't answer my question.
What I want is to have index.php redirects to index.html.
But index.php is essential to Zend.

Comment: Can you add a real life example of why you would want to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just want something like this? (Before the rules you have, just below the `RewriteEngine On`):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.html$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: The problem is that index.php is essential to Zend. and I will have an infitite loop ( I guess)
index.php redirects to index.html, then, if index.html doesn't exists, redirects to index.php. Which then redirects to index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Pending a better solution, maybe this can help you:
Create an index.html with a redirection like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=index.php">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tim is right, this is about routing strategy within your Zend project rather than modifying .htaccess.

Only two lines of code (tested):

**In your bootstrap.php:**

```
protected function _initHomeRoute(){

    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('home', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/index.html', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index')));
}
```

Now try visit yourdomain/index.html.

Tim is also right about doing this is pointless in SEO. You do need better SEO people.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I already have index.html that renders a page correctly.
What I want is to have : 
http://MYDOMAIN/index.php to redirect to http://MYDOMAIN/index.html